# Wrong Battery levels getting shown in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: power-management, battery, indicator, 22.10

I have recently shifted from Zorin OS to Ubuntu 22.10. I tend to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu.
Since I have started using Ubuntu, I have noticed that the battery seems to be not discharging (according to the battery icon in the top right side). It shows the same state the battery was in when I booted the laptop. There have been times when my laptop has suddenly powered off without giving any indication that the battery charge had extinguished. I have also noticed that this problem is specific to Ubuntu (does not show up in Windows 10).

I tried to check battery information using `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/uevent` command. This turned up:
[terminal on execution of the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdUKm.png)

I tried check battery power using `acpi` command.
Both methods showed similar levels. The battery icon displayed the same level. The above image was taken at a time when battery level is supposed to be full(battery led is white) and the laptop is plugged in. Neither is getting indicated.

Please help me understand the error.

P.S. : It's my first question on StackExchange. Hope I have been able to adhere to community standards.